# white patch issue after clicking md-autocomplete and md-select

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Once clicking on md-autocomplete textbox i am getting a white patch from the bottom of the page and it is hiding the other form field..
style is automatically generating in body element..

Kindly suggest me some solutions.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Screeshot of my project web layout]

Comment: Disable loading of all CSS files except **angular-material.min.css** and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Ya after removing other css file its working fine, now i have to find which css is conflicting.. Thanks btw